# Converting Powershell Script to VBScript to grab aircard information

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm having a bit of trouble converting this Powershell script into VBScript.

All of my Echo statements at the beginning of my VBScript display correct data, so I know my initial WMI query is working, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my `fQueryModem` function.

I've seen other sites suggest `MSCOMMLIB` or `System.IO.Port` SerialPort Class, but I tried those options and couldn't get any to work.

When I first launch the script I receive no error, but there is no output when I try to echo the values stored in the variables that called the function. Any subsequent launch of the script throws this error: `"The requested resource is in use Code: 800700AA Source: (null)"`

Also, I'm not sure if I correctly converted the portion of the script that takes a regex pattern and matches it against `tVar`.

Please, any help or suggestions are welcome, because this has had me scratching my head for a week now.

Powershell:

```
Function fQueryModem($sQueryString, $sRegExp) {
    $oComPort = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $sComPortNumber,$sComPortSpeed,None,8,1
    $oComPort.Open()
    $oComPort.Write("AT")
    $oComPort.Write($sQueryString + "`r")
    Start-Sleep -m 50
    $tVar = $oComPort.ReadExisting()
    $tVar = ($tVar -replace "OK","").trim()
    $oComPort.Close()

    If (!($sRegExp -eq "")) {$tVar -Match $sRegExp|Out-Null; $tVar = $Matches[0]}
    return $tVar
}


#Populate Variables using fQueryModem Function Call
$sMEID = fQueryModem "+CGSN" "\d{15}"
$sModemModel = fQueryModem "+CGMM" "" #Match Everything
$sPhoneNumber = fQueryModem "+CNUM" "\d{11}"
$sSIM = fQueryModem "+ICCID" "\d{20}"
#$sFirmwareDate = fQueryModem "+GMR" "\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}"
$sFirmwareDate = fQueryModem "+GMR" ""
```

VBScript:

```
Function fQueryModem(strQuery, strRegExp)

    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Const TristateFalse = 0

    Dim oRE, oMatches, tVar, fsoR, comR, fsoW, comW

    fQueryModem = ""

    Set fsoW = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set comW = fsoW.OpenTextFile(strComPortNumber & ":" & strComPortSpeed & ",N,8,1", ForWriting, False, TristateFalse)
    comW.Write "AT"
    comW.Write strQuery & "`r"
    comW.Close()

    wscript.sleep 50

    Set fsoR = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set comR = fsoR.OpenTextFile(strComPortNumber & ":" & strComPortSpeed & ",N,8,1", ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
    tVar = comR.ReadAll
    tVar = Trim(Replace(tVar,"OK",""))
    comR.Close()


    If strRegExp <> "" Then
        Set oRE = New RegExp

        oRE.Global = True
        oRE.IgnoreCase = True
        oRE.Pattern = strRegExp
        Set oMatches = oRE.Execute(tVar)

        Dim oMatch
        For Each oMatch In oMatches
            fQueryModem = oMatch.Value
        Next
    Else
        fQueryModem = tVar
    End If

End Function


strMEID = fQueryModem("+CGSN","\d{15}")
strModemModel = fQueryModem("+CGMM","")
strPhoneNumber = fQueryModem("+CNUM","\d{11}")
strSIM = fQueryModem("+ICCID","\d{20}")
strFirmwareDate = fQueryModem("+GMR","\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}")
```

Comment: What's the problem you've encountered? Error message? Unexpected behavior? Something else? Please edit the question and add more details. Do not paste code or errors as a comment, those are hard to read.

Comment: Please distill your problem down to a [mcve], nobody wants to read through two giant blocks of code!

Comment: @vonPryz  - I've updated my question with your recommendations and those of James C..